# Correct syntax for onclick calling javascript by passing Clientid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image]

```
<input type="button"  name="btnConfirm" value=" Confirm "  
style="font-weight: bold; display: none" 
Onclick="OnConfirmButtonClickOfDepositional(this,'<%= hidFldDepositional.ClientID %>','<%= hidDepostionalLevel.ClientID %>');"/>
```

Comment: Please provide more details or provide your complete code.

Comment: near to "this" it is showing "Unterminated String Constant" and "Expected')' "

Comment: i have uploaded the image.that is the error thrown by vs

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="clickFunction('value')"></button>
```

Value will be replaced with your expression. So it becomes

```
<button onclick="clickFunction('<%=expression%>')"></button>
```

Comment: It is Showing "unterminated string constant" and "Expected')'"

Comment: Then you're probably missing some quote. check out the generated onclick value. Every quote inside double quotes needs to be escaped or it should be replaced with single quote to work in Javascript.